# Add 'trade day' dataframe

Tags: python

I would like to add a df that shows the trading day of the year. I only want actual trading days, so no weekends or holidays.
For example:
Date         Trade Day
Jan 2, 2020   1
Jan 3, 2020   2
Jan 6, 2020   3

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import yfinance as yf
import pandas_datareader as pdr
import datetime as dt 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

ticker = 'NVDA'

#Data time period
now = dt.datetime.now()
startyear = 2017
startmonth=1
startday=1
start = dt.datetime(startyear, startmonth, startday)

#get data from YFinance
df = pdr.get_data_yahoo(ticker, start, now)

df
```

Answer (score 1):

to install the package

```
pip install pandas-market-calendars
```

And here is the code

```
import pandas_market_calendars as mcal

# Create a calendar
nyse = mcal.get_calendar('NYSE')

# Show available calendars
print(mcal.get_calendar_names())
early = nyse.schedule(start_date='2012-07-01', end_date='2012-07-10')
print(early)
```

Let me know if you want anything else as well or if i missed something

Comment: I did see this on the PyPi website, however, I am unsure of how to add a dataframe that shows what the trade day is for the year. I would like to show Jan 2 as a 1, Jan 3 as a 2, Jan 6 as a 3, etc...